# I cannot make excel vba to use application separator in windows 10 while I can in windows 7

Tags: vba, excel

I've been searching for two days to solve my issue but so far nothing.

There are many (Very many) vba excel tools developed where I work and our regional settings in PC-s determine comma as decimal separator but reports and data downloaded from our systems have dot as decimal separator. In these tools, when needed we just have set `UseSystemSeparators = False` then `DecimalSeparators = "."` and at the end of the macro reverted back.

Now new people have been getting windows 10 pcs and some of the tools run into errors. I got a Win10 pcs from IT to test and found out that no matter how I set in Excel settings VBA Macro uses PC regional settings while on the sheet it still uses what is determined in Excel settings. Same file, same test in my win7 pc and if set then both on sheet and vba macro use local application settings.

Does anyone know what is the reason and how it could be fixed? I can figure many workarounds but all of these mean that the tools need to be re-coded and there are just so many of these that I still keep finding out new tools used and what were developed before I joined the company in March. Changing all ~300 PC-s regional setting is not an option because it needs to be comma as decimal separator normally.

Edit: just to make it bit more clear I'll add some code:

```
Sub test()
    Application.UseSystemSeparators = False
    Application.DecimalSeparator = "."
    variable = "10.1"
    MsgBox CDbl(variable)
End Sub
```

Under Windows 7 - no problem. The variable containing a string can be converted.
Under Windows 10 - Run-time error, Type mismatch. Both PCs have "," as system separator. The funny thing is that when I change "10.1" to "10,1" then that works on both PC-s. Settings for both PC-s are same. System uses "," as separator and Excel is set to use ".".

Comment: Is there a specific line of code that is producing an error on one of the windows systems?

Comment: Well the problem is usually when data is imported by xml request and then used as a number in calculation. Convering to number gives also the same error. I get type errors. I tried also "variable = CDbl("10.1")" and got the same error. When I used "10,1" then no issue what so ever.

Comment: What happens in Windows 10, when you set the decimalseparator to "." and then you debug.print it?

Comment: I'd imagine it would return "." provided `UseSystemSeparators = False` but would return "," if `UseSystemSeparators = True`?

Comment: Is it *only* Windows version that had changed, or the office and Excel version as well? If so, which version are you using?

Comment: I tried Debug.Print Application.DecimalSeparator = "." while in Excel setting UseSystemSeparators is swhiched off and separator is set to "." and it printed "True". Then I added Debug.Print CDbl("10.1") and that gave Error: "Type mismatch and higlighted the added row.

Comment: Both computers have Excel 2016. Win 10 has version 15.0.4569.1504 and Win 7 has version 15.0.4884.1000. They seem close enough to me but I don't really know if this cane make that difference.

Comment: Sorry, Excel 2013 I meant. :)

Comment: @codegenerator Is this data that has been generated as a non-Excel file, and then being imported into Excel?  If so, how do you get the data into Excel?  Using VBA, a better method would be to use the `Workbook.OpenText` method which will allow you to specify the thousands and decimal separators as it exists in the data being imported.  It seems to me that this will be a more bulletproof method, especially going forward.

Comment: The data is taken from xml report. Anyhow. My point is that it works in windows 7 and it does not work in windows 10 and my question is that can Excel be put to use application setting also under windows 10 so I would not have to rewrite code in all of the tools.

Comment: The question of @RonRosenfeld is important to proceed. Also, What happens if you try `Val("10.1")` instead of `CDbl`? `Val` has the distinction that it converts strings to numbers using *only* the US decimal separator `.`, so it might be an option. Problem is it stops at any other character, so it wont recognize commas as thousands separator...

Comment: @codegenerator your test with cdbl does not show that Excel is not using a system separators.  Write the value  to a worksheet cell and see what happens. VBA is not Excel

Comment: @codegenerator also, you may have to change the thousands separator

Comment: It's good that I answered the question of @RonRosenfeld then. The data comes from a xml report. When I use Val("10.1") then it works and I get 10,1 as a number printed out(as system still uses ",".  Problem is that using Val() function would still mean re-writing the code. I still would like to know if there is way to make Excel 2013 in Windows 10 work as it does in Windows 7 so it would not use system but excel separator.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - on excel sheet they both work the same in both Windows 7 and Windows 10. If UseSystemSeparators = True then 10.1 cannot be used in a calculation and 10,1 can be. If False then vice versa as Application.Decimalseparator = ".".

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - what do I have to change the thousands separator to?

Comment: #codegenerator I do not believe you can change the decimal separator in VBA. I don't know why it worked in 2007. Possibly something in your code or data that you're not sharing with us. As far as I know, maybe a has always used only the dot as a decimal separator

Comment: That should read VBA and not maybe

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - the code I have shared in original post is full code. Works in Win7, does not in Win10. Setting in both excel apps are same. File is exactly the same.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld my point is that in Win10 vba says Type mismatch when dot is decimal separator and works when comma is. If I change System, not excel parameter into dot, then magically in Win10 vba works and gives Type mismatch with comma, not dot. Therefor I make a judgment that vba uses system separator for some reason in Win10 and in Win7 it uses how it is set in Excel.

Comment: @codegenerator I **cannot** reproduce your problem in W10 / Excel 2016 when I set my system separators to be comma for decimal and space for thousands (digits).  I copied/pasted your code and the MsgBox show `10,1`  There must be something different about your environment.  (If I use dot for the digit separators, then `10.1` gets interpreted as `101`; that's why I made it a `non-dot`).  What are your system regional decimal and digit separators when things don't work?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I tried German settings, US - chaning the separator makes sense and works. I also asked IT to put Excel 2016. Poblem is With Estonian format settings. I tried Microsoft support also but they had even hard time undestanding that EXCEL Visual Basic is not either Visio or Visual Studio. So no help from them.

Comment: @codegenerator OK, I **CAN** reproduce your problem with the Estonian language Windows regional settings. I don't know why it should occur there, and not with the same separators being used with a different locale, or with Excel 2007. However, if your code must handle input from non-Estonian locales, as well as Estonia, I suggest (unless someone comes up with a better idea) you will have to modify the code to become "internationally aware". If you search with that term, you should get plenty of information.  It will take time, but may make maintenance simpler in the future.

Comment: @codegenerator you may need to only write a single routine to handle that, and then modify your 300 VBA routines to call that single routine first.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - could you hint me bit more what do you mean by internationally aware in one callable routine. I googled and find a lot of information but some say using Format function on a string will be solution and some suggested using "|" as decimal but I cannot figure out what could be the single callable solution and what is internationally aware in vba.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld the problem with the "internationally aware" is that the original data as string comes straight from XML file so it is difficult to change this. At the moment I can come up with making a replace function that checks the system separator and if it , it changes the . from string to , and then converts to double and else it just converts to double. And then one by one if the problem occures just change the tools. Not the best solution but I think it is some kind of Microsoft bug with Estonian setting and Microsoft support told me to go to social.msdn - why, I do not know.

Comment: @codegenerator If your tools assume the Estonian setting, then a possible solution would be to pre-process your xml file with a VBA routine that would convert relevant data from whatever settings were being used to generate the data, to something that can be understood by your existing tools.  Then pass that processed file to your tool.  Only the pre-processor would have to be aware of the settings used to generate the xml file.

Answer (score 2):

### This answer is based on your system (default) DecimalSeparator being a comma (,) and ThousandsSeparator being a point (.) - using Windows 10

**Explanation:**

I've done a little testing and found that the following functions only change the `DecimalSeparator` within Excel, not within VBA:

```
Application.UseSystemSeparators = False
Application.DecimalSeparator = "."
Application.ThousandsSeparator = ","
```

This means that when you change the `DecimalSeparator` by using these lines of code, it will simply update the values in your workbooks to be displayed in the format you are specifying. For example if your system format is:

```
100.000.000,99
```

Then the lines of code above would convert the values to:

```
100,000,000.99
```

However, when you run the code above and try to use a string that uses the non-system format for the `DecimalSeparator` then VBA will not recognise it.

**Example:**

(Where `Application.DecimalSeparator = ","` when `Application.UseSystemSeparators = True`)

```
Sub TestSeparator()

Application.UseSystemSeparators = False
Application.DecimalSeparator = "."
Application.ThousandsSeparator = ","

Debug.Print CDbl("100.99")

End Sub
```

This code will return `10099`, not the expected double of `100,99` (in your system format) because VBA does not see the `DecimalSeparator` of "." as a `DecimalSeparator`.

**Solution:**

When referencing doubles within VBA you will need to always use the computer's system separators for thousands and decimals. If the doubles are being imported as strings you will need to use [Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt3szac5(v=vs.90).aspx) to convert the string into a format that uses system separators.

**Solution Example:**

(Where `Application.DecimalSeparator = ","` when `Application.UseSystemSeparators = True`)

If you have the string of `"100,000,000.99"` in cell `A1` and use the following code:

```
CDbl(Range("A1").Value)
```

It will produce a "Type mismatch" error. However if you convert this into a string that uses your system separators then no error will be given. You will need to use two `Replace` functions though, one to remove the `ThousandsSeparators` and one to convert the `DecimalSeparators` to your system ones:

```
CDbl(Replace(Replace(Range("A1").Value, ",", ""), ".", ",")
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But the thing is that... in windows 7pc everything works. I set Application.UseSystemSeparators = False, Application.DecimalSeparator = "." And I can convert string "10.1" with CDbl into a double. When I do the same in windows 10 pcs I get the Type error.

Comment: The solutions shouldn't change, you'll just need to apply a `Replace` function to the strings which will stop the error from happening on Windows 10 and will not affect the Windows 7 PCs as they will still function as normal with the `Replace` functions

Comment: As I said there ase so many different tools that I would really wish to avoid spending my next three months reprogramming them. I can figure out many workarounds, as I said in original post. What I wish to find out is how to make Excel work as it does under windows 7 or to find out if it really is not possible then I can let everyone know that all the projects in my worklist will be postponed three months.

Comment: I feel it should be emphasized more that `CDbl` was never meant to respect `Application.DecimalSeparator`. It either never did and generated slightly/not so slightly off values without the OP noticing, or there was [something really strange](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41258972/i-cannot-make-excel-vba-to-use-application-separator-in-windows-10-while-i-can-i/43745727#comment69807905_41258972) happening, but the point is, `CDbl` only respects the system separators by design, and any code that assumes different must be changed.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps this:

```
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Name of Worksheet")
ws.Cells.Replace What:="", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _ SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=True, ReplaceFormat:=True
Set ws = Nothing
```

Comment: Mad Physicist Thank-you for formatting. I should have mentioned that to make Decimal and Thousand separators to work, I insert in ThisWorkbook module the following: Private Sub Workbook_Open(), 
tmpBool = Application.UseSystemSeparators, Application.UseSystemSeparators = False, End Sub; tmpBool can be set as Boolean in a Main Module, and then: 

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean), Application.UseSystemSeparators = tmpBool, End Sub

Comment: If you put UseSystemSeparators inside a single Sub, it will revert to its original state once the Sub closes, not allowing your Decimal and Thousand separators changes to stay active.